# Use of gdal.TranslateOptions in python - scale values to 8 bit

Tags: python, raster, gdal, gdal-translate

I am trying to write a script in python that does some processing on raster files: Convert to 8 bit, compress to LZW and specify tiles size. My script does everything except scaling correctly from 16 bits to 8 bits. I have tried the same in the osgeo shell and it works perfectly. Can someone spot what is the problem with the python script: I attach here the python script and the osgeo shell command.

Python script:

```
from osgeo import gdal
from osgeo import gdalconst
print(help(gdal.TranslateOptions))

listtifs= glob.glob(r"PathtoFolder\Faulty\*.TIF", recursive=True)
print(len(listtifs))
outFolder=r"PathToFolder\Faulty2"
translateoptions = gdal.TranslateOptions(format = 'GTiff',outputType = gdalconst.GDT_Byte,creationOptions = ["TILED=YES", "BLOCKXSIZE=256", "BLOCKYSIZE=256", "COMPRESS=LZW"])
n=1
for i in listtifs:
    outdatasetTR=outFolder+"\\"+i.split("\\")[-1]
    print("Opening raster ",n,": ",i)
    indataset = gdal.Open(i)
    outfile=gdal.Translate(outdatasetTR, indataset, options=translateoptions)
    print("Translating raster ",n,": ",i)
    n=n+1
    indataset= None
    outfile=None
```

In the python script I did not use the unscale option as I have seen that if omitted is set to False.

And the working osgeo shell command:

```
gdal_translate -ot Byte -of GTiff -scale -co compress=LZW -co BIGTIFF=YES -co TILED=YES -co BLOCKXSIZE=256 -co BLOCKYSIZE=256 "PathToFolder\Faulty\NoName_WV3.tif" "PathToFolder\Faulty2\NoName_WV3.tif"
```

Comment: Your gdal_translate command does not convert into "byte" because I don't see  `-ot byte` in the command. Is that just a typo?

Comment: Hi, you are right, I had copied from a previous command. Edited the post, thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: You do not give the `-scale` option at all in your Python script. Add it.  `-unscale` is unrelated and you did not use that in the shell command either.

Comment: there is no "-scale" option in the gdal.Translate options for python. The help just shows "unscale" and "scaleParams". You mean to calculate the raster min and max  myself and to pass it to "scaleParams"? I thought there will be just an equivalent of"-scale" for python

Comment: Like `-scale` on command line can take parameters `[src_min src_max [dst_min dst_max]]`https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html#cmdoption-gdal_translate-scale but it does not need to, I suppose that using empty scaleParams is OK `scaleParams=[[]]`.

Comment: Thank you, using empty scaleParams solved the issue!

Comment: Please write that as an answer and include the working Python code.